# Keeping the Stata Data Viewer focused at a given row

Tags: stata

Suppose I'm looking at the 1000th row of my dataset in the Data Viewer (or in the Data Editor), When I execute a command such as order, sort, or replace, the view is reinitiated at the 1rst row. Is there a way to change this behavior? I was under the impression that this did not happen with my previous version of Stata 12 (I'm using Stata 13 now).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try updating and see if the problem is resolved.